# How to take screenshot of drop-down menu with Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, html-select

I am new to Selenium and to C#. I am trying to create an automation code to a website and saving screenshots of the elements of each step. 
Figured a way to save screenshots only of specified elements, however the drop-down menus are not appearing on the saved images.
Tried using the PRTSC option which is doing the job but taking images only of the screen and I only need image of the drop-down menu and not the whole page. 
Is there a way in Selenium that I can take screenshot only of the drop-down list?
Any idea or advice is welcome.

Comment: Two options come to mind: take the full screenshot but crop it to the element on the page, or take the full screenshot but simply highlight the element required.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same, to have screenshots of dropdowns. I figured that, on using the keyboard strokes: Alt+Down arrow we can open the dropdown. 
The same can be done by below:

```
//Alt key code is 18, the below does the alt key stroke
selenium.KeyDownNative("18");

//Down arrow key code is 40, the below does the downkey stroke
selenium.KeyDownNative("40");

//Takes screenshot
selenium.CaptureScreenshot(@"d:\Image.jpg");

//Release alt key
selenium.KeyUpNative("18");

//Releases down arrow key.
selenium.KeyUpNative("40");
```